# Can an Android app be developed using C/C++?

Tags: java, android, c++, c

I'm finishing my degree on electronics engeneering and I need to create an Android app for a project that I'm doing. The fact is that I've seen that Java is the most used language for doing that, however I'd like to know if it's possible to develop an Android application using C/C++ and which are the limitations it has. I have no experience on Java and I don't have much time to spend learning it right now.

I haven't started the coding of the app.

Comment: Asking for tools/books/recommendations is off-topic here.

Comment: @jason he didn't ask for any of that

Comment: Yes it's possible. Google for "android ndk" or even just "android c++"

Comment: The gist of the question is *"... and which are the limitations it has ..."*.  The closure reason is arguably incorrect.  IMO it should have been closed as "needs more focus" ... or maybe "opinion based".  But I also agree with Alan: google it and do some preliminary reading and you should get an idea of the limitations *that are relevant to your and your project*.

Comment: Our application is cross-platform and written in C++ for around 90%. It runs on Android, with some Kotlin (and Java) code to interface with Android UI, and on iOS with help of some Objective-C and Swift UI wrappers.

Comment: I’m voting to reopen. This is a simple direct specific question. It deserves an answer.

Comment: I'm also voting to reopen. I agree with @BasilBourque - this question is not _"seeking recommendations"_ at all, and the close reason is completely bogus. This is a simple question that has a factual answer. Can any of the close voters explain how they interpret this question to be _"seeking recommendations"_ and _"is likely to lead to opinion-based answers"_?

Comment: Yes, possible, but you need to find a suitable framework. I know SDL2 can do this, but it's primarily targeted at games (lacks gui widgets).

Comment: [1] I voted to reopen your question yesterday. However, it seems to be a clear duplicate of [Android application only in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64369616/2985643). That has a useful and relevant accepted answer, so I'm now voting to close your question. To avoid closure, can you possibly reframe it to ask something more specific? [2] The old, closed question [Why shouldn't an Android app be written in C/C++ because you "simply prefer to program in C/C++"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13773686/2985643) may also be of interest.